# Cloud Hybrid Search and custom schema and query rules

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, administration, 2019, hybrid-search

The docs don't seem to mention what to do about having custom managed properties, query rules, etc., when configuring cloud hybrid search. Do I understand correctly that these configurations will need to be manually reconfigured in SharePoint Online?

SharePoint Online can export/import search configuration. Can the search config be exported from on-premise SharePoint and imported to Online?

Also, what about full crawls? If I configure Cloud Hybrid Search and then set up custom crawled properties in SharePoint Online, I would need to run another full crawl via the on-premise cloud SSA? Or, do I need to put in a ticket with MS for SP Online to run a full crawl?